# rbenv not overriding default Ruby version

Tags: terminal, macos, ruby, zsh

I used the [thoughtbot laptop script](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) to setup a new Macbook Air (OSX 10.10.5), but when I navigate within a Rails project that contains a `.ruby-version` file, running commands such as `rails s` returns an errors of: `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3`.

Running `rbenv local` within the same directory gives the correct version of 2.2.3.

I'm running the commands in zsh with the following .zshrc:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash zsh)"

# recommended by brew doctor
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

I just want to be able to run the Rails app locally and will use something other than rbenv for Ruby version management if need be.

Comment: Have you got ruby installed via Homebrew as well as rails (i.e. how did you install rails)

Comment: Neither ruby or rails show up with `brew list`, but rbenv and ruby-build do.

Comment: You likely are, but are you prefixing your commands with `bundle`? E.g. `bundle install`, `bundle rails s`, etc?